# How to get all possible bundle packages

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here's a sample of my data:

[image]

I'm trying to write a query that returns all the possible bundle packages for insurance_product and how many customers have the same bundle package.

here's the query I wrote but I only get 2 values in a package (I need to get also ship+house+car+life):

```
select concat(insuranct_product1,insuranct_product2) as bundle_package,
count(distinct customer_id) as customer_count
from(
select t1.customer_id, t1.insuranct_product,t2.insuranct_product
from customers t1
join 
customers t2
on t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id
where t1.insuranct_product<t2.insuranct_product
) group by concat(insuranct_product1,insuranct_product2)
```

Comment: So you want all possible combinations of ship+house+car+life -> {ship},{ship, house},{ship,car}...{ship, house,life} ... i.e. 2^4 - 1 in total. Then the count of customers which have each combination?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY customer_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT insurance_product) > 1` to find the bundles with multiple products and then `LISTAGG` aggregate them together. Then you can aggregate by the bundles to count the number of customers for each bundle:

```sql
SELECT bundle,
       COUNT(*) AS customer_count
FROM   (
  SELECT customer_id,
         LISTAGG(DISTINCT insurance_product, ',')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY insurance_product)
           AS bundle
  FROM   customers
  GROUP BY customer_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT insurance_product) > 1
)
GROUP BY bundle
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (customer_id, insurance_product) AS
SELECT 1, 'Car' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Car' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Car' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Car' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Ship' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Ship' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Ship' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'House' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'House' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| BUNDLE | CUSTOMER_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| Car,House,Ship | 2 |
| Car,Ship | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hQDVkObv)